# TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined

Tags: javascript, event-handling, discord, discord.js, typeerror

I am coding a discord bot with discord.js and after adding an event folder to clen up my `index.js` file the `ready` event that I had doesn't work anymore and I haven't changed a single line.

This is the new `ready` event

```
const { testserver, creator } = require('../../../config.json')

module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
        console.log(`Connected as ${client.user.tag}`);
        const MyUsername = client.guilds.resolve(testserver).members.resolve(creator).user
        const OnlineEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Online!')
        .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('By ' + MyUsername.tag, MyUsername.displayAvatarURL());

        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('channelid');
        channel.send(OnlineEmbed);
        channel.send('=======================')
}
```

This is the error I get

```
(node:22076) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined
    at module.exports (MyDir\MyBot\main\events\client\ready.js:4:49)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (MyDir\MyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:431:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (MyDir\MyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:415:10)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (MyDir\MyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:197:14)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at WebSocketShard.checkReady (MyDir\MyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:473:12)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (MyDir\MyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:445:16)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (MyDir\MyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:299:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (MyDir\MyBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
```

This is the code for the event handling

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
    const load_dir = (dirs) => {
        const event_files = fs.readdirSync(`./main/events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))

        for (const file of event_files) {
            const event = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);
            const event_name = file.split('.')[0];
            client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client))

        }
    }
    ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e))
}
```

And this is my index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { token } = require('../config.json');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
})

client.login(token)
```

What can I do? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your event handling folder with this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
  const load_dir = (dirs) => {
    const event_files = fs.readdirSync(`./main/events/${dirs}`).filter(file => 
    file.endsWith('.js'))

    for (const file of event_files) {
        const event = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);
        const event_name = file.split('.')[0];
        client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, client, Discord))

    }
}
  ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e))
}
```

**What you did wrong?**

> client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client));

In this line, you mention "Discord" first, so When invoking you ready.js, It finds for .user in "Discord" which returns undefined.